# Cancel pending transaction (bitcoinj)

Tags: bitcoinj, java

I'm using bitcoincashj (https://github.com/bitcoinj-cash/bitcoinj) I created a transaction and sent it. But it didn't broadcasted to network. Can I cancel this transaction?

Current wallet status is:

```
{
    "currentAddr": "mikpGRFT5aVfFsRyezbUrRdY9Ju8Fu3Wdj",
    "balance": 140523875,
    "balanceAvailableSpendable": 140523875,
    "balanceEstimated": 5417277385,
    "balanceEstimatedSpendable": 5417277385,
    "balanceBtc": "1.40523875 BCH",
    "balanceEstimatedBtc": "54.17277385 BCH",
    "peersCount": 2,
    "transactions": [
        {
            "txid": "854a9f0844ace104dbd2011323e48f80ca61436512a9734dd488580c3fcce54a",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "4c83d41c3165751653a648f052a147852aa47366e7400a4e588d3c1f6146cc08",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "c1e8caebcc8e0ae291ee2bfe5ecb003c8acbe95a63e8f71c9386f42e1c997c4d",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "f301d99e5946bdb7d17379546ba3780a1b4e65c685d86e6b161dd8c67f030614",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "559ede6ccf495e4f36de0caf809830792ec899cc74c12875a529e70702aaceb6",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "1004bf183e35ae91a14a50122f7c369cdb95aae4eed05929326a10d47eefc5b1",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "03db4f583c874740d045ff750f8a33647f707d5090b4fa5c1877caecfecaa755",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "76f8acb77fc2cccb637e4923e736cfb29a3690e9d4b29b0dd654d982d38aa428",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "645799394af9ef3307f11fe54e9f87720d5d2372f9092a998ba4379e0b25ff00",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "e8d51902ecd1c1919a4472574854789e41bcd11f2b3d92c45528762fe550a1f6",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "104fef5e7b72fe3ed34e74467f8066c9cc0db957881308b3f3ca3eceb576f507",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "74e6f7f7d9c0370d256d70dae1997c233d2806e612250601812fba4a4b70cec1",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "53a41dfecb6362dcf795abf9361db08cd3ccf24f2837b88b50773eef48646c12",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "957fec5c71a9de8d7561a4a2685b6dc2a3c6a66a6037d0b6d6e00b6b19c553b3",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "e10ecd7c5a19ce42a9243ef39a289c6668fe5e06508949335f9966569867521d",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "eddea91ebeae406c2955f2f6a80a171974c90b755d8d4a3003b703c530d9c563",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        },
        {
            "txid": "5317b2149b0404ed7c9f30424268074d1f4b96efd34c4a21182ef9dea79dda62",
            "pending": true,
            "cached": false,
            "coinBase": false
        }
    ],
    "addresses": [
        "mhtmbhZgiRLL79VKmrm8idusWsxffASURq",
        "n3dVoukpHkRxxMotAoWK4ziBc1hDpsWjxh",
        "mp5pQ1PFawNw3uvnTM6UWm7w34jNFrfJ6A",
        "mk5EAxCxpR1yg3EzM7MsPDYAWePuhG33L4",
        "moVwNyGKefpWUog2feVp25osgyckccy5XH",
        "n3GxYyyNEth7SFaCbjT8eqTdcjYQNk42gz",
        "mtmhJuPwSwqReVUJbXJ1a6LE9cT5ZBM9VM",
        "mtwuvFpUxvbnLURgv215QNE9wMKuHC5rbm"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your transaction wasn't broadcast, it never happened. You can simply use the inputs in another transaction.

Comment: There is estimated balance in my wallet. Can I spend them with use inputs again?